# Autowiring in EJBs and accessing application context in static variable

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, static, ejb

We are trying to enable autowiring in EJBS.

We have an interceptor for the EJB for autowiring, this interceptor gets the applictation context from a static variable in a different startup class. This startup class contains and initializes the application context. However when we try and access the appContext static variable from the interceptor it is null and when we access it from outside in the Controller or an InternalService it is not null.

We have two contexts, the application context and the web context.

We are storing the application context in a static variable in a class. We load the application context dynamically in the following manner and store it in a static variable

```
            // Create Context
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(path);

            // Register Context
            AppInitializer.ctx = context;
```

In addition to this we are storing the WebApplicationContext in a similar way as well.

```
        XmlWebApplicationContext webContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        webContext.setParent(AppInitializer.getApplicationContext());
        webContext.setConfigLocation(path);
        webContext.setServletContext(getServletContext());
        webContext.refresh();
```

This initializes the two application contexts. The EJB is mapped in the parent (non-web) application context in the following way

```
<!-- Service Register -->
<bean id="testService" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="testapp/TestServiceBean/local" />
    <property name="businessInterface" value="com.service.test.api.TestService" />
</bean>
```

Everything is wired fine and the application starts up without any issues, however when we try to access the applicationContext OR even a simple static long variable from the Controller or InternalService (Spring Service) we get

```
Long value = TestClass.getSampleLongValue(); //The sample long value was set by the AppInitializer class for testing with a long value
```

The value variable will NOT BE NULL and contain the long value that was set.

Likewise if we try to access the application context from the controller or internal service like

```
ApplicationContext application = AppInitializer.getApplicationContext();
```

The application variable will NOT BE NULL and contain the long value that was set

HOWEVER

When getting the application context from the static variable in an EJB interceptor (WHICH IS THE GOAL) in order to enable the internal services for autowiring as follows

```
public class ServiceAutowiringInterceptor extends SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor {

    @Override
    protected BeanFactory getBeanFactory(Object target) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) AppInitializer
                .getApplicationContext();

        return ctx.getBeanFactory();
    }

}
```

The ctx variable is null

Additionally when we try and use either of the following from WITHIN THE TestServiceBean EJB (for testing) without the interceptor these variables including the Long variable are both null

```
Long value = TestClass.getSampleLongValue(); //The sample long value was set by the AppInitializer class for testing with a long value
ApplicationContext application = AppInitializer.getApplicationContext();
```

IN ADDITION TO THIS there is a static block within the AppInitializer class which gets called on server startup. When calling the AppInitializer.getApplicationContext(); method from the controller the static block is not run HOWEVER the static block is run when calling from the EJB or the EJB interceptor.

We also tried calling the "Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();" method in the controller and EJB to see if there were two classloaders or such however both instances provided the same value

```
WebappClassLoader
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader@f5f972
```

Does anyone have any idea on why when the EJB accesses the application context (or any static variable) they appear as null and such.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here: talking about EJB, but your example look and smells like Spring?

Comment: The application is using both Spring and EJBs, we are unable to autowire any spring managed beans into the EJBs.